# test for generic method argument being a class

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have a generic method with this signature:

```
private void MyGenericMethod<T>(T arg) where T : class
{}
```

If I pass, say, an integer to this method, I get an ArgumentException that the passed value does not match the restriction.  This is great, but how can I predetermine that what I am passing will match the "class" constraint so that the exception is not thrown?

Comment: Remove the where clause and check inside the method with the `is` operator? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: The compiler does this for you, what is your broader situation where the compiler is not able to catch your case?

Comment: If you have no idea whether what you're passing in will be valid or not can you not just try/catch the exception? I agree with Adam though that seeing why you don't know what you are passing might be the key to answering your question.

Comment: Can you show the code that will generate the `ArgumentException`?

Comment: not knowing the situation you are in and assuming something is happening at runtime that bypasses the compiler check (use of reflection or something), I suggest just checking the type.  I've amended my answer below.  Beware of using `is` as this matches base classes too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will already do that for you - you should actually see:

> The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'blah.MyGenericMethod(T)'

at compile-time.

The tricky scenarios are:

- generics upon generics upon generics - all those type-constraints stack, so you end up with `where T : class` ***a lot***. Sometimes it is better to use runtime validation against `T`
- reflection (`MakeGenericMethod`, etc) - again, just check at runtime

Also, note that `where T : class` ***doesn't actually mean `T` is a class*** - it means it is a reference-type, which can include interfaces and delegates. Likewise, `where T : struct` doesn't actually mean `T` is a `struct` - it means it is a struct that is not `Nullable<>`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happens, but I want to avoid the thousands of thrown and caught exceptions that this generates. I am actually calling the method with MakeGenericMethod but the type passed is dynamic (in a loop) and I was hoping to put a simple if in before calling the method to avoid the exception.

Comment: @Craig you never mentioned MakeGenericMethod ;p Just check against the type - `!type.IsValueType` is probably good enough, or `type.IsClass || type.IsInterface`

Comment: perfect, IsClass and IsValueType is exactly what I didn't know about and was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass `int` because it is a **value type** and you have constrained your Method to accept only **reference type**.
if you want to support any of those you need to remove the generics constrain like following

```
 private void MyGenericMethod<T>(T arg)
        {
            if(arg.GetType().IsValueType)
            {
                //T is value type
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want.  I want to only pass and process reference types.

Comment: Same logic would work, check for arg.GetType().IsValueType, and call the method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You actually get compilation errors if the argument being passed is not a reference type.  If you box a value type, however, you can get around that, but then it's a valid reference type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            object o = (object)i;
            MyMethod(o);
            MyMethod(i); // Doesn't compile.
        }

        static void MyMethod<T>(T arg) where T : class
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If you are getting this error because you do something at runtime, such as use reflection to call the method, or you box value types, then you will simply need to check the parameter before you use it:

```
static void MyMethod<T>(T arg) where T : class
{
    if (arg is ValueType)
        throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Note that this will catch all value types, whether they are boxed or not.  Also note that using `is` also matches true for the type in it's hierarchy (base / derived classes), whereas checking `GetType` against `typeof` takes only the type at that level:

```
int i = 0;
bool b = i is object;
b = i.GetType() == typeof(object);
```

**Obviously in your case** you won't want to throw an `ArgumentException` and perhaps just do nothing.